# how to use logical OR operation between macro and global variable

Tags: c, embedded, logic, automotive

input.c and output.h two files, which are in different location,data in the output.c will be printed out when macro "HEXA" is activated.

consider macro "HEXA" is disabled,and i want to print the data in output.h file when i call "active_fun" function in input.c. so i have used a global variable its value is updated when function "active_fun" called and global variable is used in .h file to print data as shown below

input.c -->

```
int var=0;                                       
int active_fun (void)                                
{                                                    
  var =1;                                       
}
```

output.h --->

```
#ifdef HEXA|| (var ==1)
   printf("var value is one");
#endif
```

(i have also used #ifdef HEXA || defined(var ==1) even this logic also didn't worked)

i want to print the data in .h file when macro "HEXA" is activated and by the active_fun (when macro "HEXA" is disabled).

is there any other way to print the data in .h file.

Comment: You can use `if ( HEXA || (var ==1) {
   printf("var value is one"); }` [but you need to have HEXA #defined as zero in this case]

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "print data in `.h` file".  Normally header files should only contain declarations, macro definitions, etc, and should never contain code that actually does something like `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should prefer being direct and readable:

```c
int should_print = var;
#ifdef HEXA
should_print = 1;
#endif
if (should_print)
{
    printf("var value is one");
}
```

Alternatively:

```c
#ifndef HEXA
#define HEXA 0
#endif

if (HEXA || var)
{
    printf("var value is one");
}
```

Note: I've also simplified your `var` checks on the assumption that it will only ever be 0 or 1.

Comment: These differ from the original code. If `var` is a value other than 0 or 1, these will print, but the original code (as intended) will not.

Comment: @Eric Yes, I should have noted that I intentionally made that change since the original code shows only 0 and 1 as possible values.  It seems far more likely to me that it's meant to be a boolean. If `var == 1` is actually necessary, then that's a trivial adjustment.

Comment: IMO, can't use another macro since its value will be replaced in compilation and i want to print, when i call the "active_fun"

Comment: The second alternative will cause problems if there are `#ifdef HEXA` blocks further down in the program.

Comment: @anu I don't understand. If you want `active_fun` to print when called, why can't you just make its body unconditionally call `printf`? I also don't understand what you mean by "can't use another macro since its value will be replaced in compilation".

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
/*
 * If x can be expanded then the expanded version will be stringified
 * unlike regular #x
 */
#define PPSTRFY(x) #x
#define IS_MACRO_DEFINED(m) strcmp(#m, PPSTRFY(m))

/* --- */

if (IS_MACRO_DEFINED(HEXA) || var == 1)
    printf("var value is one");
```

It only won't work if you `#define HEXA HEXA` but I don't see why you would want to do that. And if you're not including `string.h` I think replacing `strcmp(#x,  PPSTRFY(x))` with `(#x != PPSTRFY(x))` should work the same since identical string literals should have the same address.